# How to test an HTTP 301 redirect?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, telnet, http-status-codes

How can one easily test HTTP return codes, like, say, a 301 redirect?

For example, if I want to "see what's going on", I can use *telnet* to do something like this:

... $ **telnet nytimes.com 80**

```
Trying 199.239.136.200...
Connected to nytimes.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**GET / HTTP/1.0**

**(enter)**

**(enter)**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1
Date: Mon, 14 Jun 2010 12:18:04 GMT
Content-type: text/html
Set-cookie: RMID=007af83f42dd4c161dfcce7d; expires=Tuesday, 14-Jun-2011 12:18:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.nytimes.com
Set-cookie: adxcs=-; path=/; domain=.nytimes.com
Set-cookie: adxcs=-; path=/; domain=.nytimes.com
Set-cookie: adxcs=-; path=/; domain=.nytimes.com
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Cache-control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>    
<head>      
...
```

Which is an easy way to access quite some infos.

But now I want to test that a 301 redirect is indeed a 301 redirect.

How can I do so?

Basically, instead of getting a *HTTP/1.1 200 OK* I'd like to know how I can get the 301?

I know that I can enter the name of the URL in a browser and "see" that I'm redirected, but I'd like to know what tool(s) can be used to actually really "see" the 301 redirect.

*Btw, I did test with a telnet, but when I enter www.example.org, which I redirected to example.org (without the www), all I can see is an "200 OK", I don't get to see the 301.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, two minutes after answering the question I found the answer...

Doing the following doesn't work:

```
telnet www.example.org 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
{enter}
{enter}
```

But the following works fine:

```
telnet example.org 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.org
{enter}
{enter}
```

My error was to pass *www.example.org* to *telnet* (instead of *example.org*) and then not specifying any *"Host: "*.

Now it works, I get this:

```
Connected to xxx.xx
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.org

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://example.org/
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 14 Jun 2010 13:02:22 GMT
Connection: close

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Note: On Windows Vista/7, Telnet Client is not installed by default.  To install it, follow the directions here: [Install Telnet Client - Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_installVista)

Answer (score 22):

A far more convenient solution in my opinion is to use Curl.

Simply run:

```
$ curl -I http://example.com
```

And it will return the HTTP headers like this

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 10:41:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 161
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://other.example.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to test it is to specify a 301 redirect on the target website and use `curl -L` option to inform you of 301 redirects.

```
-L, --location

(HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different 
location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option 
will make curl redo the request on the new place.
```

For example:

```
:~$ curl -IL mail.com
```

You get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 13:17:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.mail.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 13:17:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Host
Set-Cookie: cookieKID=kid%40autoref%40mail.com; Domain=.mail.com; Expires=Thu, 09-Mar-2017 13:17:13 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: cookiePartner=kid%40autoref%40mail.com; Domain=.mail.com; Expires=Thu, 09-Mar-2017 13:17:13 GMT; Path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://www.mail.com/int/
Content-Language: en-US
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 13:17:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Host,Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: cookieKID=kid%40autoref%40mail.com; Domain=.mail.com; Expires=Thu, 09-Mar-2017 13:17:13 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: cookiePartner=kid%40autoref%40mail.com; Domain=.mail.com; Expires=Thu, 09-Mar-2017 13:17:13 GMT; Path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=964DA3BD186E264928A8C188E3BB919D; Path=/mailcom-webapp/; HttpOnly
Content-Language: en-INT
Content-Length: 74356
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox addon [HTTP Live headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) is quite useful for that.

Comment: ah interesting, thanks for that link...  However I was looking for something more "low level", like *telnet* :)   Funnily I found a way to get my 301 two minutes after posting the question :)

Answer (score 1):

In the headers (of the telnet response) you'll see it in the first line:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Via: XXXXXXXXXXX
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 14 Jun 2010 13:03:14 GMT
Location: /xxxxxxxxx
Server: XXXXXXX
Cache-Control: private
```

Thanks

Comment: actually you don't in the way I showed in the question, which was the whole point of my question :)   Look at my answer to see why it wasn't working in the way I was trying using telnet and what needs to be done to make it work :)

Comment: You didn't had the 301 on the first line because it wasn't one. If the "www" version does it  but not the "non-www" version, it's not the problem of telnet nor my answer. it's because one of the two URL does it and the other not. These are 2 different URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s [*Net* panel](http://getfirebug.com/network) for this.

[image]